# problems using universal image loader for downloading images and showing them in custom listview?

Tags: universal-image-loader

I am new to android programing and i am now facing an issue in a task. I have made my custom listView which is showing data parsed from a JSON object. Now, I also have to show images which are to be downloaded from the internet. For that purpose I am trying to use universal image loader from github, but when in my adapter class I do

```
imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
```

I get the error on init saying

> Syntax error on token "init", Identifier expected after this token

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show please more code: where ```imageLoader``` and ```context``` vars are declared.